# signal r in react how to know if there's no data coming from sockets?

Tags: reactjs, sockets, next.js, signalr

the problem I'm facing is I'm creating a connection to my hub and then invoking some URLs to that connection and all of the responses are arrays, the problem is that the sockets don't return an empty array for example this is my code.

```
connection.on(MarketIRT, (items) => {
     setIRTMarket(items)
});
```

So if there are any items in that socket there is no problem, the problem only occurs when there's no data in them so basically when `items = []` .
how should I know when there are no items in there so I can show a placeholder or even a loader?

Answer (score 0):

```
connection.on(MarketIRT, (items) => {
    // check if items is actually array
    // and if it's empty
    if (Array.isArray(items) && items)
      setIRTMarket([])
    else 
      setIRTMarket(items)
});
```

Comment: the problem is it doesn't get called when the items are empty, I mean I know it's empty because I have access to the data of backend, but it doesn't even get called whenever the items are empty like you can't access it.

Comment: Suggest you to make a quickhack to see if it works, basically  when you sending empty array from backend try sending [-1] or something alongside ['empty'] and check if your theory works correctly, if your frontend does't receive that, probably there's a bug in your backend

Comment: i think this is from backend to, thanks you for your time.